# Change folder name with Git and then commit changes?

Tags: git, directory, git-commit, mv

I Need to rename my `CSS` folder on `css` folder, but if I rename it manually git would not see any changes.

I have tried to do this:

```
git mv CSS css
```

but I get the following error:

```
fatal: renaming 'CSS' failed: Permission denied
```

So what is the right way to change folder name using `git`?

Comment: Which operating system? I can imagine Windows and OSX have  problems when only changing the case

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `git mv` just performs the rename and adds all affected files to the index. You can always manually rename with `mv` and `git add` later. What happens if you do this instead?

Comment: @knittl: windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Windows cannot rename files to a name which only differs in case. You'd have to first rename it to a different name:

```
git mv CSS CSS_
git mv CSS_ css
```

Comment: @MichaelVayvala: will `-k` actually move the file? From the documentation I would assume it just hides errors.